# WPF - Binding ObservableCollection to ListView

Tags: wpf, listview, binding, observablecollection

I'm capturing images using my usb webcam (aforge library) and storing captured images in `ObservableColection`

```
public ObservableCollection<BitmapImage> Images { get; set; }
```

`Images` is a property of my view model class.

```
class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged

    private ObservableCollection<BitmapImage> images = new ObservableCollection<BitmapImage>();
    public ObservableCollection<BitmapImage> Images
    {
        get
        {
            return this.images;
        }
        set
        {
            if (images == value)
                return;
            this.images = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Images"); // Using the INotifyPropertyChanged interface to raise property change events
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }
```

in my `SecondWindow` I want to display captured images in a `Listview` I have. Tried this binding:

```
private SecondWindow OwnerWindow;
public MainViewModel OwnerWindowViewmodel { get; set; }
```

and in Constructor

```
this.OwnerWindow = (SecondWindow)window;
this.OwnerWindowViewmodel = OwnerWindow.OwnerWindowViewmodel;
OwnerWindowViewmodel = (MainViewModel)this.DataContext;
```

Xaml:

```
<ListView x:Name="ListView" ItemsSource="{Binding Images, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Height="345"  Margin="567,10,10,0" VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <ListView.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <UniformGrid Columns="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemsPanel>
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                        <Image Source="{Binding}" Height="150" Width="150"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

but there is nothing in my `Listview`. I have tested by adding breakpoints and debugging the count of captured images and its correct at the breakpoint (Let's say that I have captured 2 images, count of Images are 2)
How could I get captured images displayed in my `Listview`?

Comment: Any binding errors in debug output?

Comment: Is you ViewModel set as DataContext in your View?

Comment: How do you think we could help you when you don't give us the most basic information? How do you create and show a SecondWindow, and how do you pass a view model instance to its DataContext?

Comment: As a note, setting `Mode=TwoWay` and `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` on the ItemsSource Binding is pointless.

Comment: I have set ViewModel  as DataContext in my View

Comment: @Clemens why you are that aggressive? it's not working thats why I'm asking here!

Comment: I have updated my question...

Comment: We still don't see any code where you set the DataContext of a SecondWindow, so "I have set ViewModel as DataContext in my View" seems not to be true. Take another close look at the answer to your previous question.

Answer (score -2):

I do not see anything wrong with your code, I think the problem is with the BitmapImage collection.
Please find the correct way to initialize a BitmapImage:

```
BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage();
image.BeginInit();
image.UriSource = new Uri(@"C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\Lighthouse.jpg");
image.EndInit();
```

OR

```
BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\Lighthouse.jpg"));
```

PS: This is just for example, make sure you are initializing your images in a similar manner.

Comment: Besides that is doesn't answer the question, what you show here is not "the correct way to initialize a BitmapImage", but just one way. You may as well use the BitmapImage constructor with Uri parameter, and thus save the BeginInit and EndInit calls.

Comment: I used the same code in my test project and I could see the images (which I loaded locally), if the collection is fine then there must be an issue with the data context binding.